# pandas read_csv error when loading CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, read.csv

I want to open a simple csv file (notepad file) using python, called '123123'

```
hello,hallo,hoihoi
123,123,123
34,34,46
```

I want to run it using the following code;

import pandas as pd

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'\C:\Users\Jette\Documents\pythonProject\123123.csv', engine="python", sep=',', encoding='latin-1')
```

However, I keep getting the following error.

```
C:\Users\Jette\Documents\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Jette\Documents\pythonProject\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jette\Documents\pythonProject\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    data = pd.read_csv(r'\C:\Users\Jette\Documents\pythonProject\123123.csv', engine="python", sep=',', encoding='latin-1')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 948, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 611, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1448, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1705, in _make_engine
    self.handles = get_handle(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\pandas\io\common.py", line 863, in get_handle
    handle = open(
             ^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\C:\\Users\\Jette\\Documents\\pythonProject\\123123.csv'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I can find similar questions and answers online, but they do not work for me.
Can somebody help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: chk file path is incorrect.

Comment: `r'\C:\Users\Jette\Documents\pythonProject\123123.csv'` should be `r'C:\Users\Jette\Documents\pythonProject\123123.csv'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have invalid path. Try do it as follows:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Jette\Documents\pythonProject\123123.csv', engine="python", sep=',', encoding='latin-1')
```